# Moving from MySQL to MySQLi with mysql_result PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So initially, I know that using the `MySQL` extension is not good for security and it's not updated but I only had used it for learning but now I want to move to MySQLi and I am not sure how I can convert it. I have two problems and I am not sure where to go as you can see below for the first set of code.

What I want to do is check if a server is active and this is defined in a database where the table looks like this

[image]

So if active is equal to **1** then that is *true*, if not then it should be *false*.

```
function server_active_query($data) {
    $server = sanitize($data);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`server_id`) FROM `servers` WHERE `servername` = '$server' AND `active` = 1"); 
    return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true: false;
}

//This is the new function so don't worry about the name
function server_active_query($data) {
    $dbc = new mysqli('db_host', 'db_user', 'db_pass', 'db_db');
    $server = sanitize($data, $dbc);
    $query = $dbc->query("SELECT COUNT(`s_id`) FROM `servers` WHERE `servername` = '$server' AND `active` = 1"); 
    //Not sure where to go from here as It does not work.
    return (mysqli_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true: false;
}
```

Comment: How is it a duplicate? You didnt even read this question... I am not asking pros and cons, I am asking for some support buddy @MeeneshJain

Comment: ok bro removed my comment if you are switching from mysql to mysqli procedural then your queries remain the same, what you need is change the way you created the connection and the way you write your query

Comment: Seems to me you need to learn prepared statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stick with the OO mysqli calls and the one you are looking for is $result->num_rows which returns the number of rows returned by the SELECT query.

Using ->query() returns a `mysqli_result` object and that does not have the ability to return you the data from column 0 like the the mysql_ extensions does, so change the query to select a field, so it only returns a row if it find a server in the active state, then you can use the `->num_rows` property

```
function server_active_query($data) {
    $dbc = new mysqli('db_host', 'db_user', 'db_pass', 'db_db');
    $server = sanitize($data, $dbc);

    $result = $dbc->query("SELECT `s_id` 
                           FROM `servers` 
                           WHERE `servername` = '$server' AND `active` = 1"); 

    return $result->num_rows == 1 ? true: false;
}
```

Or to use the better prepare() style

```
function server_active_query($data) {
    $dbc = new mysqli('db_host', 'db_user', 'db_pass', 'db_db');
    $server = sanitize($data, $dbc);

    $stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT s_id
                           FROM servers 
                           WHERE servername = ? 
                             AND active = 1"); 

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $server);
    if ( $stmt->execute() ) {
       $return = $stmt->num_rows == 1 ? true: false;
    } else {
       // error processing code or just default to false?
       $return = false
    }

    // as we have not actually processed the returned row 
    // we had better clean up the statement handle
    $stmt->close(); 

    return $return;
}
```